# Where do Harbingers spawn?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I'm trying to get **Meat Boy** and **Bandage Girl** achievements and this is driving me nuts.

I know I have to defeat all 4 [Harbingers](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/The_Harbingers) (a.k.a The Horsemen) in one run, but I can't find them. It's not easy to find the [Book of Revelations](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Book_Of_Revelations), and each time I get it I find a *Double Trouble* boss room that ruin my run, or one of the other Horsemen that drop a *Pony* item (Headless and Conquest).

I've tried the [Monster Manual](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Monster_Manual) strategy, too, but in 7 hours and 30+ *Manual* activations I haven't got a damn *Cube of Meat* at all.

So I'm pretty discouraged, and I've restarted my runs infinite times because of wrong bosses. This is a slow process.

To save a bit of time, I've heard that **Harbingers** only spawn as the first boss of each set of floors (Basement/Cellar, Caves/Catacombs, Depths/Necropolis and Womb/Utero). So my question is:

*Is this true? Or should I try to fight Basement/Cellar II boss before restarting?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Famine can appear on Basement II

Harbingers can spawn on any floor once they have been unlocked, except floors with a preset boss (Depths II, Womb II and onwards). This means it is worth trying Basement II to see if famine spawns there.

Because getting the achievements is easier before Conquest is unlocked, it may help to begin a new profile, earn the achievements on that without unlocking Conquest, and sync your original save with your Steam achievements.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. It's not a bad idea to start over with another profile; in the old Binding of Isaac it was easier to "build" a Meat Boy, so I didn't mind when unlocking Conquest.

Comment: @pinckerman The old BoI didn't have Bandage Girl to interfere with Meat Boy, so it was definitely easier to build the Super version. Also there weren't Double sized rooms that could ruin your attempt, so the Headless Horseman and Conquest were less of a problem

Comment: Are you sure that Famine can appear on Basement 2? Yesterday I've found Book of Revelations in a Library Room after I've defeat Basement 1 boss, then I moved to Basement 2 to activate the book. The result? Larry as boss, **not** Famine. I don't understand.